# How to disable audio of only one HDMI / Displayport port?

Tags: sound, multiple-monitors, pulseaudio, pavucontrol

I have two monitors connected via Displayport to different ports of the same GPU. I want to permanently disable audio of one monitor, and keep audio in the other one.

Pavucontrol is very useful at disabling hardware entirely (i.e. the webcam's mic). But I cannot find a way to disable audio from Monitor 2 while keeping Monitor 1 intact.

I'm happy with PulseAudio's hot swapping and it works great when switching on & off the audio interface, headsets, and so forth. Disabling hot swapping is not an option.

Maybe a solution could be hardcoding every device output in /etc/pulse/default.pa, but this sounds (pun intended) overkill and a potential source of other problems. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the monitors daisychained?

Comment: No, the GPU has several Displayport ports and each monitor is plugged independently.